# How to get values that only exists in all arrays

Tags: php, logic

I am looking for some kind of solution for my problem. It's rather thinking problem.

I have array which looks like this:

```
$mainArray = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [5, 4, 2]
    [2, 4, 3] 
]
```

From this array I want to only get $result = [2], because value 2 exists in every "sub array".

Can someone help me with some logic tips to achieve desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to core developers, [`array_intersect`](https://www.php.net/array_intersect) can work with 2 or **more** arguments:

```
$mainArray = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [5, 4, 2],
    [2, 4, 3],
];
print_r(array_intersect(...$mainArray));
// outputs:
Array
(
    [1] => 2
)
```